# Python Converting string into datetime for finding difference

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file that exports dates like this - 2020-04-10T17:04:17.536Z and 2020-04-13T15:18:07.327Z

df2 and df3 split this into this format - 2020-04-10 and 2020-04-13

I want to be able to subtract these two dates  to get days but keep getting the error - TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

I am still very new to any type of programming and would greatly appreciate any help

Also some of df3 will be blank, so how do I set it up to insert the current date so it has something to subtract?

```
import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
df1 = pd.read_csv (import_file_path)
df2 = df1['CreateDate'].str.split('T').str[0]
df3 = df1['ResolvedDate'].str.split('T').str[0]


create_date = df2
resolved_date = df3
def Avg_Lifetime(date_str):
    return datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y, %m, %d')
    
    
created = Avg_Lifetime(create_date)
resolved = Avg_Lifetime(resolved_date)

df9 = resolved - created
```

Comment: Just use `pd.to_datetime`.

Comment: Omg that was so easy! Thank you! Everything I found was complicated and wasn't working lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = {'created':['2020-04-10T17:04:17.536Z'],
     'resolved':['2020-04-13T15:18:07.327Z']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['created']=pd.to_datetime(df['created'])
df['resolved']=pd.to_datetime(df['resolved'])

df['difference'] = df['resolved']-df['created']
```